# Can you take a value of an array and use it in a variable

Tags: java, variables

I have 26 variables (case1, case2, ...)
I have 26 buttons. (btnCase1, btnCase2, ...)
Is there a way to do this;

```
final JButton btn18 = new JButton("18");
    btn18.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn18.setText(Integer.toString(cases[18]));
            picked = cases[18];
            btn18.setEnabled(false);
            btnNext.doClick();
            casesPicked++;
        }
    });
    btn18.setBounds(785, 281, 100, 100);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn18);

    final JButton btn19 = new JButton("19");
    btn19.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            btn19.setText(Integer.toString(cases[19]));
            picked = cases[19];
            btn19.setEnabled(false);
            btnNext.doClick();
            casesPicked++;
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to say something like this:

```
 final JButton btn18 = new JButton("18");
    btn18.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             int i = 18
            btn[i].setText(Integer.toString(cases[i]));
            picked = cases[i];
            btn[i].setEnabled(false);
            btnNext.doClick();
            casesPicked++;
        }
    });
```

I need to be able to do this later on in the code to recall what cases have already been chosen.

This is my current full code. http://pastebin.com/9Am3jMQ8 Probably the worst code you guys will ever read.

Comment: What exactly do you need to be able to recall later in code? Also, you could declare all of these buttons in a for loop, since they do the same thing but with a different number.

Comment: why do you want btnNext.doClick();? What datatype is cases?

Comment: Well, first, how could I do this in a loop if they set a different case to false? I would need to say btn[number of button].setEnabled(false);. And as for what I need to access later, I want to know what buttons were clicked on because every 6 buttons clicked I need something else to pop up, disable all the currently enabled buttons, prompt the user something then re enable all the buttons it just disabled. (probably making this confusing) It's for the game Deal or no Deal

Comment: @BOND cases is an array with different integers stored to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you take a value of an array and use it in a variable?

Yes.

---

---

I would create a class for your `ActionListener`.  In it you can define exactly what you want it to do and provide it the data it needs to do it.

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener
    {
    private final JButton button;
    private final JButton btnNext;
    private final int index;

    public MyActionListener(final int index,
                            final JButton button,
                            final JButton btnNext)
        {
        this.index = index;
        this.btnNext = btnNext;
        this.button = button;
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event)
        {
        picked = cases[i];
        this.button.setText( Integer.toString(cases[i]) );
        this.button.setEnabled(false);
        this.btnNext.doClick();
        casesPicked++;
        }

    }
```

Then you can set this up, [without repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself):

```
final JButton btn18 = new JButton("18");
btn18.addActionListener( new MyActionListener(18, btn18, btnNext) );
frame.getContentPane().add(btn18);

final JButton btn19 = new JButton("19");
btn19.addActionListener( new MyActionListener(19, btn19, btnNext) );
frame.getContentPane().add(btn19);
```

You could then easily change your button creation to use a loop:

```
for (int btnNum = 0 ; btnNum < 20 ; i += 1)
    {
    final JButton btn = new JButton( ""+btnNum );
    btn.addActionListener( new MyActionListener(btnNum, btn, btnNext) );
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn);
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I want but I'm not understanding it entirely. Is there any program you'd feel comfortable using to explain to me in words what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to make all the buttons work dynamically. This can be done by making a class that implements ActionListener, and writing dynamic code inside that, that will work with all your buttons. Something like this:

```
public class ButtonClick implements ActionListener {

    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    //More buttons
    btn18.addActionListener(this);
    btn19.addActionListener(this);

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        //Use a global variable as a count for the number
        //of buttons clicked

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            JButton thisButton = (JButton)source;
            Integer caseNumber = Integer.parseInt(thisButton.getText());

            thisButton.setText(cases[caseNumber].toString());
            //Any other code you need
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can implement Jbutton  array like below :

```
    JButton button[] = new JButton[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        JButton btn = button[i];
        btn = new JButton("Button " + i);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        jPanel2.add(btn);//adding button to a panel
        // set Layout to your panel as u can display all ur buttons in kind of order 
//Ex. jPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    }
```

**Implement actionListener interface to your class**

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "Button " + 0:
            System.out.println("pressed button 0");
            break;
        case "Button " + 1:
            System.out.println("pressed button 1");
            break;
        case "Button " + 2:
            System.out.println("pressed button 2");
            break;
        case "Button " + 3:
            System.out.println("pressed button 3");
            break;
        case "Button " + 4:
            System.out.println("pressed button 4");
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

}
```